# Jupyter Notebook Python 3 Append Module Cannot be called

Tags: python, jupyter

[image]

I used append function earlier in my code and it worked. However, it is not working in this specific loop and it is giving me this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the append function, instead with IHCImage. It does not seem to be a function, instead a module you imported

Comment: How can I fix it then?

Comment: You have not shown us how you import or define `IHCImage`.

Comment: it seems `IHCImage` is module and you have to use some `IHCImage.function()` and you should know what function it has to be - or check it in documentation.